# how to keep different or specific firebase account for each nodejs projects

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, visual-studio-code, firebase-authentication

I use npm firebase-tools to deploy nodejs web app. 
I have multiple projects running and I'm facing a problem when I logein a firebase account it logedin in all projects.
when i move to other project first i loge out and then loged in for that account to deploy (as other projects are hosted on different email).
Is there any way to keep a specific account logedin for single project

Answer (score 0):

For firebase Admin in Backend:
you can use singleton design pattern to create instance for your classes.
for example

```
class Firebase{
     constructor(key){
              this.firebase = Firebase.initialze(key);
     }
}
module.export = Firebase
```

then you can create how many instances you want like this:

```
const FB = require("my-firebase-class);
const fb1 = new Firebase("my-key-file1");
const fb2 = new Firebase("my-key-file2");
```

[[UPDATED]]:

For Frontend According to

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects

```
var secondaryAppConfig = {
projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
appId: "<APP_ID>",
apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
// databaseURL: "...",
// storageBucket: "...",
};
```

and for using

```
var secondaryApp = firebase.initializeApp(secondaryAppConfig, "secondary");
```

Comment: I'm working on static websites inside public directory. i don't know where to use this code and how to get Firebase.initialze(key)

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's for firebase admin , I updated my answer, i hope it will works, i didn't try before